# Issue using wait.for in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, wait

for npm module in node to try and get these functions to execute synchronously: saveFlightDetails needs saveFlight to complete first, which in turn needs saveItem to complete first... and each set of those 3 functions needs to complete before the loop iterates to the next set of data.

I've got a for loop that has the below code inside it, with my data set it iterates twice (2 flights).

```
function saveData(app, data, i){

            var Item = app.get('models').Item;
            var Flight = app.get('models').Flight;
            var FDeparture = app.get('models').FDeparture;
            var FArrival = app.get('models').FArrival;
            var currentItem = [],
                currentFlight = [];

            wait.for(saveItem, data, Item, i, currentItem, currentFlight);
            console.log('currentItem: ' + currentItem);
            wait.for(saveFlight, data, Flight, i, currentItem, currentFlight);
            console.log('currentFlight: ' + currentFlight);
            wait.for(saveFlightDetails, data, FDeparture, FArrival, i, currentItem, currentFlight);


    }

    wait.launchFiber(saveData, app, data, i);
```

and saveItem, saveFlight and saveFlightDetails go to other functions that save the data to db. This is saveItem but the others look very similar:

```
function saveItem(data, Item, i, currentItem, currentFlight){   
 console.log('Entered item function.');
 Item.create({ 
     ...
    }).success(function(item){
     console.log('Created item.');
     currentItem = item;

    });
}
```

For some reason which I can't seem to explain, the loop iterates twice as expected but the output is:

```
Reached saveItem function.
Reached saveItem function.
Item saved.
Item saved.
```

The saveFlight and saveFlightDetails functions arent being called along with those console.logs for currentItem and currentFlight, BUT saveItem runs correctly...

I thought this would call saveItem and wait until it completed, then call saveFlight and wait, then call saveFlightDetails and wait. and THEN iterate. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the answer. For those who may find this useful as there's not alot of example docs on wait.for, I needed to create more fibers. So instead of having one fiber for one function saveData with 3 wait.for calls in it, I needed 3 fibers each with their own function, each with one wait.for call in it. Psuedocode below:

```
function save1(args){
    wait.for(asyncfunction1, args);
    console.log('save1 done.');
}

function save2(args){
    wait.for(asyncfunction2, args);
    console.log('save2 done.');
}

function save3(args){
    wait.for(asyncfunction3, args);
    console.log('save3 done.');
}


wait.launchFiber(save1, app, data, i);
wait.launchFiber(save2, app, data, i);
wait.launchFiber(save3, app, data, i);
```